# What would happen if I earned 200 reputation on multiple sites at the same time?

Tags: discussion, reputation, association-bonus, association

Let's say, from the perspective of Stack Exchanges servers, I earned 200 reputation on multiple sites at once. Obviously, earning 200 reputation would award an association bonus, but are there specific safeguards in place against earning multiple at the same moment?

In other words, if I earned 200 reputation on say Math SE, and Stack Overflow at the same time (from the server's eyes), would I improperly be awarded 200 reputation as association bonuses? Would I earn 100 reputation? Would nothing happen at all, or would a moderator be summoned to sort out the situation?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Whether or not you have the association bonus is simply a setting on your network account that is basically set to true or false. It is awarded once per site the first time that is flipped to true. So a subsequent site passing 200 close together would not trigger the system to re-award the association bonus to every site again.

*Even if* you somehow managed to get the system to do this, the system would take the second bonus away the next time your reputation was recalculated, as having two is invalid.